# Rails - No route matches [GET] "/index.html" (For ALL Routes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I'm trying to deploy my Rails app to a staging environment for the first time. I'm pretty sure this is an Apache/Passenger issue, but I'm not sure where to even look to fix it. I probably just need to add a rule to my conf file, but I don't know what that rule would be. Maybe some sort of rewrite rule, since it appears to be looking for a file instead of parsing the route?

The issue is: for EVERY SINGLE route, it appears to be converting it "behind the scenes" into "/index.html" - whether I try "/api/v1" or "/api/v1/users" or "/api/v1/channels/authorize" (or any others).

The apache2/access.log file seems to show the route being passed properly:

```
[07/Dec/2019:18:23:15 +0000] "GET /api/v1/channels/authorize HTTP/1.1" 500 41024 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
```

And the apache2/error.log file doesn't show any errors.

---

Here is my conf file. I'm using an alias to parse between two separate apps (/api/* goes to the Rails backend, everything else goes to the VueJS front-end -- I know I could embed the client into the Rails public directory, but I'm doing it this way for my own reasons).

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName <my url>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/client

     # configure error logs
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

     # Passenger config stuff
    PassengerEnabled off
    PassengerRuby /path/to/ruby
    PassengerAppEnv development
    PassengerStartTimeout 400


     # if the route matches https://<domain>/api/*
      # then point to the Rails API app
      # (and use Passenger to serve it)
    Alias /api /path/to/railsapp/public
     # configuration for the /api routes
      # basically just enable Passenger and tell it where to point to
    <Location /api>
        PassengerEnabled on
        PassengerBaseURI /
        PassengerAppRoot /path/to/railsapp
    </Location>
    <Directory /path/to/railsapp/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted

#       RailsEnv test
    </Directory>

     # for EVERYTHING ELSE, point to the VueJS client app
    <Location />
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
    </Location>

     # and of course enable SSL and point to the certs
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/chain-file

</VirtualHost>
```

This is the first time I've done anything with Passenger. I tried to just cobble together something from the examples I found online, but it's very possible I've missed something along the way.

Comment: +1 for a working Passenger config. Note that `Allow from all` is Apache pre-2.4; `Require all granted` is sufficient for Apache 2.4+ (ie. since 2012).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've figured it out. The `RewriteRule`s in the following block are getting applied to everything:

```
<Location / >
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</Location>
```

(every route in Vue gets rewritten back to the index.html file -- but Rails doesn't do that).

So I tried a few things that different work before eventually figuring out that I can simply add a `RewriteCond` to the rule set to exclude all calls to `api/*`

So the new block is:

```
<Location / >
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api/*        ## THIS IS THE LINE TO ADD!
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</Location>
```

That one line is all I had to add to the apache conf file to get it working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `PassengerBaseURI /` under `<Location /api>` to `PassengerBaseURI /api`.

Comment: I thought of that! I tried it and it did nothing to fix the error I'm getting. Additionally, I do need it to do that (or else I need to go back and change every one of my routes in Rails to remove the "/api" prefix). Otherwise all of the routes end up being "/api/api/v1/{whatever}"